# Rails4 - How to write tests for boolean variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I write test for presence and validity of boolean values?

db/migrate/[timestamp]_add_admin_to_users.rb

```
add_column :users, :is_female, :boolean, default: false
```

app/models/user.rb

```
validates_inclusion_of :is_female, in: [true, false]
```

test/models/user_test.rb

```
  test "gender should be valid" do
    @user.is_female = "0"
    assert @user.valid?
    @user.is_female = "1"
    assert @user.valid?    
    @user.is_female = "f"
    assert @user.valid? 
    @user.is_female = "t"
    assert @user.valid?     
    @user.is_female = "false"
    assert @user.valid? 
    @user.is_female = "true"
    assert @user.valid?       
  end

  test "gender should be present" do
    @user.is_female = "     "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end
```

I get the following error.

```
suai@tutorial:~/workspace/converse (gender-birthday) $ rake test
Run options: --seed 54502

# Running:
    ......................F.........................................
    Finished in 5.003949s, 12.7899 runs/s, 59.9527 assertions/s.

  1) Failure:
UserTest#test_gender_should_be_present [/home/ubuntu/workspace/converse/test/models/user_test.rb:26]:
Expected true to be nil or false

64 runs, 300 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
suai@tutorial:~/workspace/converse (gender-birthday) $
```

I am a newbie. Is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This(#the failure is because you are checking with some space)

```
 test "gender should be present" do
    @user.is_female = ""
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end
```

Comment: Thanks @anusha. But my other tests fails when I add validates_presence_of :is_female

Comment: @NewtoRails Oops..! is there any other field for you to check gender or `is_female` only

Comment: @NewtoRails I think you have reversed your condition try my updated answer

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M001898 says that "If you want to validate the presence of a boolean field (where the real values are true and false), you will want to use validates_inclusion_of :field_name, in: [true, false]."

Comment: @NewtoRails yes it is true check updated answer once

Comment: I get the following.   1) Failure:
UserTest#test_gender_should_be_present [/home/ubuntu/workspace/converse/test/models/user_test.rb:26]:
Failed assertion, no message given.

64 runs, 300 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Comment: Shouldn't it be assert_not @user.valid? ?
It passes when i use  
test "gender should be present" do
    @user.is_female = ""
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

Comment: @NewtoRails yes you are correct sorry my mistake i checked now i will update it